# EmailMessage not showing on lead's Activity Timeline

Tags: emailmessage, activity-timeline

I am trying to log an email message on a lead/contact. The `EmailMessage` is getting logged correctly but it's not showing on the Activity Timeline for the lead/contact.

```
    EmailMessage m = new EmailMessage(
        Subject = 'email.subject',
        TextBody = 'email.plainTextBody',
        HtmlBody = 'email.htmlBody',
        ToIds = new Id[]{ leadContactId });
    insert m;

    EmailMessageRelation r = new EmailMessageRelation();
    r.emailMessageId = m.Id;
    r.relationId = leadContactId;
    r.relationType = 'FromAddress';
    insert r;
```

Here's the `EmailMessage` record showing a link to my sample lead record:

[image: EmailMessage record]

And here's the Activity Timeline on the lead record:

[image: Activity Timeline on lead]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to update the **status** field on the EmailMessage object. Set it to **3** to indicate the message was sent.

```
EmailMessage m = new EmailMessage(
Subject = 'email.subject',
TextBody = 'email.plainTextBody',
HtmlBody = 'email.htmlBody',
Status = '3',
ToIds = new Id[]{ leadContactId });
insert m;
```

This automatically creates a TaskId and links the Task to the Email Message